# Is there a way to determine when UIPickerView has reloaded?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am calling `reloadAllComponents` in my code. I want to be able to execute some code once `UIPicker` has reloaded, sort of like how `viewDidLoad` works.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the apple documentation for UIPickerView and could not find any method which gets notified when the loading of data is complete.

However you could try the below mentioned approach.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
    [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Do something after reloading of UIPickerView data is complete.
}];
```

*Note: Please mark as answer if this solves your problem.*